# Deleting posts via Django command doesn't work

Tags: python, django, django-commands

Deleting posts via Django command does not work. I do not know what to do, I am at a dead end. I hope you can help me...

**delnc.py** File command

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Командa для удаления всех постов из категории'
    requires_migrations_checks = True
    missing_args_message = 'Недостаточно аргументов'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('category_name', type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        print('Мастер код: 7548')
        answer = input('Введите Мастер код для удаления: ')

        if answer == '7548':
            try:
                category = str(options['category_name'])
                Post.objects.filter(postCategory__category_name=category).delete()
                Post.save()
                self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS(f'Успешно. Все новости категории {category} удалены!'))
            except Post.DoesNotExist:
                self.stdout.write(self.style.ERROR('Нет такой категории! Отказано!'))
        else:
            self.stdout.write(self.style.ERROR('В доступе отказано!'))
```

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name

class Post(models.Model):
    PostAuthor = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор поста')

    PostNews = 'PN'
    PostArticle = 'PA'

    # «статья» или «новость»
    POSITIONS = [
        (PostArticle, 'Статья'),
        (PostNews, 'Новость'),
    ]

    postCategory = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name='Категория поста',  through='PostCategory')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Название')
    positions = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=POSITIONS, default=PostArticle, verbose_name='Тип поста')
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='Категория', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category_id')
    data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата создания')
    data_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата редактирования')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name='Фото', blank=True, default='/photos/def/1.jpg/')
    previewName = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Превью поста')
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Текст поста')
    rating = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Рейтинг')
    public = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Опубликовано')

    def like(self):
        self.rating +=1
        self.save()

    def dislike(self):
        self.rating -=1
        self.save()

    def preview(self):
        return self.text[0:124] + '...'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пост'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Посты'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/news/{self.pk}'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        cache.delete(f"new-{self.pk}")
```

*Here is the output from the console*

[image]

But he does not delete anything, although he writes that everything was completed successfully

Comment: the call to `Post.save()` does not do anything, because it is called on the model class and not on an instance. I don't think you need that call, because `.delete()` already does the work.

Comment: You can check the filtered objects doing multiple steps instead of one step: `posts = Post.objects.filter(postCategory__category_name=category)`, then `print(posts)` and finally `posts.delete()`; this will show you if any objects were found